# Number of possible six digit password for a debit card using integers (0-9)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Customers can choose a six digit password for their debit card using one of the 10 integers (0-9)

(a) how many possible passwords that contain two odd numbers?
(b) how many possible passwords that contain at least one number 3?

I have tried to solve these two questions a multitude of different ways however I cannot quite grasp exactly what is being asked for.

So far I have:
 $\binom52\binom54$ for choosing two of the odd numbers from the 5 total and then placing the two odd numbers in a total of 4 spots within that group of odd numbers but I am still missing something.

As for the second question I am not sure where to start. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For a) assuming what is meant is "have exactly two odd digits", then there are $\binom 62$ ways to choose the  two positions which have odd digits. This gives a pattern like odd-even-even-even-odd-even. For each of these there are $5^6$ passwords, since you have $5$ choices for an odd digit and $5$ for an even digit. So the answer is $\binom 625^6$. Your approach is incorrect because it is possible to use the same digit more than once (and because you don't consider which positions in the password the odd digits are in).

For the second question, Mikko Pesonen is correct: there are $9^6$ which *don't* work, so $10^6-9^6$ which do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming same number can be used multiple times

a)
There are $5$ different odd numbers and $5^2=25$ different pairs which can be placed in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways. The rest $5$ numbers can then be placed in $5^4$ ways.
This gives $5^2\binom{6}{2}5^4=\binom{6}{2}5^6$ combinations total.

b)Password may contain 1 to 6 of $3$:s
In complement case there doesn't exists any $3$:s on the string.

Total cases: $10^6$, cases not including number $3$: $9^6$
So amount of cases with any amount or $3$:
$10^6-9^6$

EDIT: fixed faulty a, should be correct now.